# ejabberd add iq handler

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I have created an iq handler. When calling it, it prints me this error

```
{function_clause,[{jlib,iq_to_xml,[ok]},
                     {gen_iq_handler,process_iq,6},
                     {gen_iq_handler,handle_info,2},
                     {gen_server,handle_msg,5},
                     {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should return `#iq{}` record instead of `ok` atom from your iq handler. Let us see your code to be more specific.

Comment: send_message_delivery_ids(ResultFlags, From, To) ->
 XmlBody = {xmlelement, "iq",[{"id","aeb214"},{"to", From },{"type","chat"}],
     [
      {xmlelement, "result", [{"xmlns","urn:xmpp:requestdelivery"}], ResultFlags}
     ]
     },

 ejabberd_router:route(From, To, XmlBody).

Where ResultFlags = [  [{xmlelement,
                         "deliverystatus",
                         [
       {"messageid","DLORQ-22"},
                           {"status","1"}
        ],
                       []}]

Comment: You don't need to route the result iq by yourself. You should return it from your iq handler in #iq{} record.